# Dynamically select React component and apply data as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and I am pretty sure this can be done but I am not sure of the syntax.

```
# pseudo code
const components = [
    {component: <A />, type: "type_a"}, 
    {component: <B />, type: "type_b"}, 
    {component: <C />, type: "type_c"}
];

const Wrapper = ({type, data}) => {
   const component = _.find(components, (c) => c.type === type);
   return (
       <component data={data} />
   )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  const componentsArr = [
    {component: A, type: "type_a"}, 
    {component: B, type: "type_b"}, 
    {component: C, type: "type_c"}
 ];

const Wrapper = ({type, data}) => {
 const index = componentsArr.findIndex((c) => c.type === type);
 if(index  > -1) {
   let DupComp = componentsArr[index].component;
   return <DupComp data={data}/>
 } else {
   return (
   <div>Not found this type</div>
  )
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this ?

```
# pseudo code
const components = [
    {component: (data) => <A data={data}/>, type: "type_a"}, 
    {component: (data) => <B data={data}/>, type: "type_b"}, 
    {component: (data) => <C data={data}/>, type: "type_c"}
];

const Wrapper = ({type, data}) => {
   const component = _.find(components, (c) => c.type === type);
   return component(data)
}
```